# Delay in view setvisibilty to complete

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gesture

I was trying to create a custom view for Like and Unlike Button for a user.

[image]

If I swipe L-> R , It reveals the like button and swiping R->L reveals the unlike button.

Since clicking on top of the view is triggering click on buttons underneath, I have to make the button invisible if they are not being shown.

I am using my custom Gesture detector for detecting the scroll and moves the top view to reveal the buttons underneath.

```
 private Handler setLikeWrapperVisibility = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //    Log.i(TAG, "likeWrapper: " + (msg.what == VISIBLE ? "VISIBLE" : "INVISIBLE"));
            likeWrapper.setVisibility(msg.what);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In custom Gesture detector.

```
@Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            move(distanceX);
            if (isLeftOpen() > 0) {
                if (dislikeWrapper.getVisibility() == VISIBLE)
                    setDislikeWrapperVisibility.sendEmptyMessage(INVISIBLE);
                if (likeWrapper.getVisibility() == INVISIBLE) {
                    setLikeWrapperVisibility.sendEmptyMessage(VISIBLE);
                }
            } else if (isRightOpen() > 0) {
                if (likeWrapper.getVisibility() == VISIBLE)
                    setLikeWrapperVisibility.sendEmptyMessage(INVISIBLE);
                if (dislikeWrapper.getVisibility() == INVISIBLE)
                    setDislikeWrapperVisibility.sendEmptyMessage(VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

But there is a delay happening when the button's visibility changes to `View.VISIBLE` (may be some 500ms). Even when the top view moves from side. The button underneath in not immediately appearing.